# Oracle APEX 5.1 side navigation bar icons does not vertically aligned

Tags: html, css, oracle-apex-5.1

I started to develop a new application with **Oracle Apex 5.1**. In this application I use the **side navigation menu** as the main menu. Second level menu **list items and icons are not vertically aligned**. I tried to intercept the template defaults to solve this problem, but it does not work.

I think, I need to add
`style="vertical-align:middle;"` 
to second level menu item's icon span but I don't know where I can put this codes.

May anyone help me?

[This is the screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSXin.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this css to your page,

```
.t-TreeNav .a-TreeView-node--leaf>.a-TreeView-content .fa {
    line-height: 32px;
}
```

In APEX 5.1.4 the following CSS has the same effect without breaking the alignment on the top level menu items:

```
.t-TreeNav .a-TreeView-node>.a-TreeView-content .fa {
    line-height: 32px;
}
.t-TreeNav .a-TreeView-node--topLevel>.a-TreeView-content .fa {
    line-height: 40px;
}
```